# Checkbox Selected using JQuery is not reflected in Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a Notification list control of

```
protected global::WebControlsExtended.CheckBoxListWithAttributes
```

which looks like as follows
[image]

Now, I have used the follwing JQuery for checking and disabling a check box(say x) in the above notification list control on Client Side on the Web page
Initially the Checkbox 'x' may not be checked.

```
function ToggleManagerCheckBox(data)
    {
      if(data.indexOf("Showstopper") >= 0)
      {
          var ctrl = $("span[managerScenario='1'] input:first-child");
          ctrl.prop('checked', true);
          ctrl.prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else 
      {
          if(GetQueryStringParams("id") !="")
           $("span[managerScenario='1'] input:first-child").prop('disabled', false);            
      }
    }
```

So, when I do this the checkbox is selected and disabled as expected, but when user clicks submit on the form, I am getting whatare the selected checkboxes in the list and doing some processing on that.
 The problem is in my .NET code behind file, I cannot see the selected option for checbox as true, though I am setting it on client side using above JQuery method. I am not sure why this is happening. Here is the code on my Server side file.

```
public List<RequestConst.Notification> NotificationList
    {
        get
        {
            List<RequestConst.Notification> list = new List<RequestConst.Notification>();
            foreach (ListItem item in chkBoxLstNotification.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    RequestConst.Notification notificationEnum =
                        (RequestConst.Notification)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestConst.Notification), item.Value);
                    list.Add(notificationEnum);

                }
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

Any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The browser won't send disabled fields to the server. You should look in to the [SubmitDisabledControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.submitdisabledcontrols.aspx) property to force controls disabled on the client to submit their values when the page posts back.

Comment: I tried setting the Property to True, both in my User Control and on the Page where this User control resides through this.`Page.Form.SubmitDisabledControls = true;` but it doesn't help, In the user control's code behind file, I couldn't see the disabled and selected checkbox as selected. it still shows `x.selected=false` where x is our disabled and checked checkbox using our client script

Comment: Could this be a Postback Issue? In my code, When ever a Postback Happens I am collecting what are checkboxes are selected for this control and setting them again for the purpose of Javascript functions to work correctly. However This should not affect the checkbox selection state as we are resetting to same previous values. Even in the Pageload method where I am reading the checkboxes states this client side checked box state is not refelcted as selected.  So, I can conclude that the state change of checkbox on client side using JQuery is not being sent to Server at all. How to resolve this..?